# How to add a row with data into html table using array, function partly working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, innerhtml

I would appreciate the help. I am trying to add new rows into a html table, where on click button, it adds row at random. My add function is not able to add the data from the array to row but creates the rows.

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="./javascript1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="member">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Remove</th>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Iza K</td><td>iza@mail.com</td><td><button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button></td> 
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Mima T</td><td>mimat@mail.com</td><td><button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="addFunction()">Click Me!</button>
```

JavaScript Code

```
// function deleteRow(r) {
//     var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
//   document.getElementById("member").deleteRow(i);
// }
}

 var dataArray = [{
name: "Brandon I",
email: "b.i@mail.com",
remove: "<button type='button' onclick='deleteRow(this)'>Delete</button>"     
 }, {
name: "John Bishops",
email: "johnb@mail.com",
remove: "<button type='button' onclick='deleteRow(this)'>Delete</button>"
 }];

  // need to add to select user at random when clicked add button
 const randomElement = dataArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * dataArray.length)];

function addFunction()
{ 
var table = document.getElementById('members');
for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++)
{
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var name = row.insertCell(0);
var email = row.insertCell(1);
var remove = row.insertCell(2);
name.innerHTML = dataArry[0];
email.innerHTML = dataArray[0];
remove.innerHTML = dataArray[0];
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, u have typo on `getElementById()` void, it should be `.member` rather than `.members`. After your `randomElement` variable needs to be into your function, otherwise return value of this variable will be always the same. And finally, you can directly access your properties object `dataArray` thanks to `randomElement` variable in order to set your content.
Complete code :

```js
let dataArray = [{
    name: "Brandon I",
    email: "b.i@mail.com",
    remove: "<button type='button' onclick='deleteRow(this)'>Delete</button>"     
 }, {
    name: "John Bishops",
    email: "johnb@mail.com",
    remove: "<button type='button' onclick='deleteRow(this)'>Delete</button>"
 }];

function addFunction()
{ 
      // need to add to select user at random when clicked add button
    const randomElement = dataArray[Math.floor(Math.random() *    dataArray.length)];  
    
    var table = document.getElementById('member');
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var name = row.insertCell(0);
    var email = row.insertCell(1);
    var remove = row.insertCell(2);
    name.innerHTML = randomElement.name;
    email.innerHTML = randomElement.email;
    remove.innerHTML = randomElement.remove;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="member">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Remove</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Iza K</td><td>iza@mail.com</td><td><button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mima T</td><td>mimat@mail.com</td><td><button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</button></td> 
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="button" onclick="addFunction()">Click Me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that really solved my problem. I was just not able to form code properly. The only issue is now that it produces 2 rows (duplicate) with click button. Could you help me limiting it to 1 row per click, please? @maestro

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Comment: I edited my code so that there is only one row added per click @ika

Comment: Thank you so much, that's really appreciated. :) @maestro

Comment: Glad I helped you ;)